# Words to keep attribute in StringToWordVector filter in weka

Tags: weka

What is the meaning of words to keep attribute in Weka StringToWord filter. Is it better to have higher value or not, for getting real results?

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is a good idea to set the limit as high as possible in order to retain **as many words** as possible. Words with small frequencies can marginally help the classifiers you induce later.

Keeping too many words may look like a bad idea for a matter of efficiency - the higher the number of attributes, the longer it will take to learn the model. However, you can filter the words to keep the most predictive ones using the `AttributeSelection` filter with the `Ranker` function and the `InfoGainAttributeEval` measure. In fact, you can play with the theshold in the AttrivuteSelection filter in order to keep a relatively small number of very predictive words, with independence of their relative frequency.

Additionally, do not forget to set the flag `doNotOperatePerClassBasis` to true in order to keep  all the words relevant to all classes.

Comment: Can I use AttributeSelection filter for text clustering?

Comment: It does not make sense to use `AttributeSelection` for text clustering, as the goal of attribute selection is to find attributes that are good predictors of a class, thus applying to supervised problems (e.g. text categorization) but not to unsupervised problems (e.g. text clustering).